# show only three records and then move to next line

Tags: php, html

This is a very basic problem but I am very new to PHP.
I need to show results in such scenario that only three records in same line then add `<br />` and then on next line, same thing should happend. I am unable to make its logic and in a great trouble :(
Right now, I am just using the simple way i.e.

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res_set)) {
?>
 <div><?php echo $data['name']?><img src="images/<?php echo $data['image']?>" /></div>
<?php
}
```

this is my code

```
$cnt = 0;

while ($prd = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

?>
                <div class="imageRow">
                <?php

    $cat_id = $prd['cat_id'];
$sql = "select * from tbl_category where id = $cat_id";
$cat_res    = mysql_query($sql);
$cat_data   = mysql_fetch_array($cat_res);
$cat_name   =   $cat_data['name'];


?>

                        <div class="set">
                            <div class="single first">
                                <a href="<?php echo $ru ?>admin/product_images/<?php echo $cat_name ?>/thumb/<?php echo $prd['thumb_img'] ?>" rel="lightbox[plants]"><img src="<?php echo $ru ?>admin/product_images/<?php echo $cat_name ?>/large/<?php echo $prd['thumb_img'] ?>" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" /></a><br />
                                <a href="<?php echo $ru ?>contact_form.php?id=<?php echo $prd['id'] ?>">Choose</a>
                            </div>


                        </div>

</div>
                <?php
                $cnt = $cnt++;
                if($cnt%3 == 0) {echo "<br />";}
                }

                //echo  $cnt;

                ?>
```

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: additionally, mysql_fetch_array() is discouraged, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php look into PDO or mysqli_fetch_array()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="imageRow">
<?php
$i = 0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res_set)) { ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo $data['name']; ?><img src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="imageRow"><br />';
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

Set the variable $i to a number, which will then be used to keep track of how many items you've written.

Then, within the while loop, increment $i ($i++), which is the same as $i = $i + 1;  By doing this, you always know which item you're on - whatever the value of $i is.  Some people choose to set it to 1 initially then increment at the very end - other like to set it to 0, and set it near the beginning - either is completely fine - whatever you need it to do / whichever way you like better.

Lastly, check if $i is evenly divisible by 3 (kind of like remainder - it's called "mod" and is represented by the percent symbol).  If it is, then echo a line break.

Comment: Thanks but see my edit, it gives me each record in a new line :(

Comment: @Muhammed Ahmed Baig Then don't put every image in a `div` or use css to change the display properties of the `divs`.

Comment: @MuhammedAhmedBaig - probably because you have `<div class="imageRow">` around each item.  Next time, try to include the actual code the first time around.  I've edited my answer to wrap your 'imageRow' around 3 divs instead of every one like your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
echo "<div>";

while($data = mysql_fetch_attay($res_set)) {
?>
 <div style="width:30%; float:left"><?php echo $data['name]?><img src="images/<?php echo $data['image']?>" /></div>
<?php
}

echo "</div>";

?>
```

Output

```
<div>
    <div>1</div> <div>2</div> <div>3</div>
    <div>1</div> <div>2</div> <div>3</div>
    <div>1</div> <div>2</div> <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's just CSS and will save you the calculations

Answer (score 0):

That's some super ugly code you have there. This will do what you need, and is cleaner.

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_attay($res_set)) {
    $frame = '<div><img src="%s" /></div>';
    printf($frame, $data['image']);
    if($i % 3 == 0) { echo '<br />'; }
    $i++;
}
```

Also, `<img>` elements are already block elements to begin with, you really don't need to wrap another `<div>` around them.